Any default command to swap the selection text
I’m quite noob in Neovim, not sure if it has builtin feature of key command to swap the selection text with its " (clipboard) register.
So anyone kind enough to clarify or laborate ?

By "selection", do you mean Visual mode where commands are usually Normal mode commands such as p to "put", or Select mode where you're essentially in Insert mode with a selection to be replaced?

Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

This is the default behavior of the put command p.
If you select a text and hit p:

the selection is replaced by the content of the default register
the default register is replaced by the selection

Remark: is the clipboard option is set not unnamed the default register used is * the system clipboard.

Problem
here;
p is key remap to P, & is only used, while never use original p
OK trying to have a key-bind for this p

You might find :help put-Visual-mode of interest.
This explains how p works in Visual mode to overwrite the selection.
I found the following side notes most interesting:

(Implementation detail:
it actually works by first putting the register after the selection and then
deleting the selection.)

Since that's what Vim will do internally, that's what I'd also do.
To swap clipboard and Visual selection, I'd ...

leave Visual mode with Esc
put the clipboard's contents with "+p
re-enter Visual mode with gv
delete selection to clipboard with "+d

That's just three simple and common commands.
As a general rule in Vim, if you don't find a command that does exactly what you want, create a mapping, e.g.
:xnoremap <Leader>p <Esc>"+pgv"+d

There's another way to do it.
If you don't want to touch the clipboard option as suggested in Vivian's answer, you could also put your clipboard over the selection and then assign the contents of the unnamed register to the clipboard with :let @+=@".
A bit more clunky (and frankly, I don't like it myself) but it could be helpful when you delete your selection and think "oh wait, I wanted to have that in my clipboard".
As a last (and slightly better) idea, at least on X11, you can make clever use of the fact that the Visual selection is stored in the PRIMARY register.
That means you could insert with "+p and find your previously selected and now overwritten selection in "*.
See :help quote+ for more details.
